# Buying Interrail pass abroad without passport

Tags: trains, schengen, passports, interrail

When buying an Interrail pass in Norway I have to bring my passport (or know my passport number). My problem is that I ordered a new passport very recently and will most likely receive it the day I leave or the day after. I will travel by plane to Prague and start taking trains from there. This means I won't have time to buy the Interrail pass in Norway.

Is it possible for me to buy the Interrail pass on the train station in Prague without my passport? All the countries I will visit are inside the Schengen Area and I can therefore travel around without bringing my passport. If my passport arrives the day after departure I can have someone pick it up and text me the passport number (and perhaps scan the passport and send me a picture that I can print and show on the train). Is it possible for me to travel around with only a regular ID card like my driver's license?

I could have gotten an emergency passport, but I hoped this should work out.

Comment: I'm not too sure about the InterRail, but the EURail pass has your passport number written on it. I highly doubt it can be issued without the passport. AFAIK, the EURail is in theory invalid without your passport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you usually need a passport or national ID to get on the plane (using web check-in you might get around that, depending on airport, airline and boarding procedure details).

Furthermore,

> Even if you don't need a passport for border checks within the Schengen area, it is still always highly recommended to take a passport or ID card with you, so you can prove your identity if needed (if stopped by police, *boarding a plane*, etc.). Schengen EU countries have the possibility of adopting national rules obliging you to hold or carry papers and documents when you are present on their territory.
>   *Driving licences, post, bank or tax cards are not accepted as valid travel documents or proof of identity.*

Source: http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm

Secondly, as explained on the [interrail.eu](http://www.interrail.eu/terms-and-conditions/conditions-use) web site:

> An InterRail pass is strictly personal, non-transferable and valid only upon presentation of a passport or other recognised travel identification document. If you travel without a passport or a legal equivalent to be presented together with the pass, you risk payment of a full-fare ticket and a fine.

Train staff usually checks not only your Interrail ticket but also that your passport or national ID's document number is the one shown on your ticket. Some train staff may accept a printed-out copy, possibly if you also show your driver's license with matching names, but I wouldn't count on it.

If you have a national ID card, just use that instead, otherwise I'd wait for the passport to arrive, or get an emergency passport for the trip.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Unfortunately, I think this was a good and accurate answer to my question. I won't accept it just yet in case someone has some additional comments.

Comment: It is a common misconception in Norway that you can travel through the Schengen area without a passport. Even if there are no regular immigration control at the borders anymore, many Schengen countries require foreigners to be able to present a passport or id card when being *in* the country. Since there are no national id cards in Norway, this leaves you with the passport as your only option. In addition to offical requirements, many air lines requires an id for check-in and many hotels/accomodations also require an id if you are planning to sleep somewhere.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Are people from Norway "foreigners" in the Schengen Area?

Comment: @AdityaSomani: Eh, yes. At least for all reasonable definitions of "foreigner". Why would you assume anything else?

Comment: Because Norway's position in Europe and EU is a bit twitchy and confusing.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you find confusing and how this is related to Norway's relationship with the EU, but a foreigner is at least defined by Merriam-Webster as a person from a different country. To be specific, foreigners must for example in Germany be in possession of a valid id. It does not matter if it is a person from an EU country like Austria, someone from Norway or someone from any other non-EU country.

Answer (score 4):

When you go to pick up your new passport, ask to keep the old one. They will void it by clipping a corner or punching a hole through it, but that is sufficient to establish the connection between the passport number on the ticket and your identity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Simon! I actually thought of this myself too,,, a few hours too late =/